# SQL question - why i can't solve a problem

Tags: sql, case

Why my solution of a problem on the study site is not accepted and showing "wrong answer"?

Here is the problem - https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem/ :

> Generate the following two result sets:
>
> 1. Query an alphabetically ordered list of all names in `OCCUPATIONS`, immediately followed by the first letter of each profession as a parenthetical (i.e.: enclosed in parentheses). For example: AnActorName(A), ADoctorName(D), AProfessorName(P), and ASingerName(S).
> 2. Query the number of occurrences of each occupation in `OCCUPATIONS`. Sort the occurrences in ascending order, and output them in the following format:
>
> There are a total of [occupation_count] [occupation]s.
>
> where [occupation_count] is the number of occurrences of an occupation in `OCCUPATIONS` and [occupation] is the lowercase occupation name. If more than one Occupation has the same [occupation_count], they should be ordered alphabetically.

My query is:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(NAME, CASE 
                  WHEN occupation = 'Actor' THEN '(A)' 
                  WHEN occupation = 'Doctor' THEN '(D)' 
                  WHEN occupation = 'Professor' THEN '(P)' 
                  WHEN occupation = 'Singer' THEN '(S)' 
               END) 
FROM   
    occupations;
```

and

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN occupation = 'Actor' 
          THEN CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(occupation), ' ', LOWER(occupation), 's.') 
       WHEN occupation = 'Doctor' 
          THEN CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(occupation), ' ', LOWER(occupation), 's.') 
       WHEN occupation = 'Singer' 
          THEN CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(occupation), ' ', LOWER(occupation), 's.') 
       WHEN occupation = 'Professor' 
          THEN CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(occupation), ' ', LOWER(occupation), 's.') 
   END 
   FROM
       occupations 
   GROUP BY 
       occupation 
   ORDER BY 
       COUNT(occupation), occupation;
```

The query has same output like in the example on HackerRank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please format your code and put it in code blocks next time.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't link to external sites with your problem description. Add all necessary information in your question to make it a [MCVE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

- The solution should work for any occupation, not just for Actor, Doctor, Profession or Singer. The tests that have different occupation data will fail.
- The first result is not ordered as was requested

First query:

```
SELECT   CONCAT(Name, '(', substr(Occupation, 1, 1), ')')
FROM     Occupations
ORDER BY Name;
```

Your second query again expects a few static occupations but will return `null` when the occupation in the test data is not one of them. Don't use `CASE` here.

```
SELECT   CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(Occupation), ' ', LOWER(Occupation), 's.') 
FROM     Occupations
GROUP BY Occupation 
ORDER BY COUNT(Occupation),
         Occupation;
```

Comment: Ye, it works! I google it(Concat) and write my own like you did it

Answer (score 1):

Explanation 1:

1. For the first part, when it is required to just print the name along with the occupation, We have cases to check the occupation and accordingly concat the suffix.
2. We use the order by clause to order the results according to the ascending order of name.

```
select 
        case 
            when Occupation = "Doctor" then concat(name,"(D)")
            when Occupation = "Actor" then concat(name,"(A)")
            when Occupation = "Professor" then concat(name,"(P)")
            when Occupation = "Singer" then concat(name,"(S)")
            else 'hello'
        end
from Occupations 
order by name;
```

Explanation 2:

All the query is doing, in this case, is to group by the results with occupation and printing the required string.

```
select "There are a total of ",count(*) as count1,concat(lower(Occupation),"s.") from Occupations group by Occupation order by count1;
```

Comment: Can you execute a `select` statement with text like that without using the `concat()` function? Also, can you add some description for what you did differently here rather than just posting some code?

Comment: Hi, @tshimkus, yes, we can execute a select statement with text like that, additionally, we have functions like LEFT and RIGHT that are used to print the text with some string manipulations. Here is a link to the same https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_left.asp. And, yes based on your suggestion,  I have added the description to my solution, It is not much different but just a different approach using case statement than the A/C solution.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. It is much more helpful now that it has some description for what the suggested code is doing.

Comment: Agreed! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> First query

```
      SELECT NAME||'('||RPAD(OCCUPATION,1)||')' FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY NAME;
```

> Second query

```
      SELECT 'There are a total of', COUNT(OCCUPATION),
      CASE 
      WHEN  OCCUPATION = 'Doctor' THEN 'doctors.'
      WHEN  OCCUPATION = 'Professor' THEN 'professors.'
      WHEN  OCCUPATION = 'Actor' THEN 'actors.'
      WHEN  OCCUPATION = 'Singer' THEN 'singers.'
      end
      FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY OCCUPATION order by count(OCCUPATION),OCCUPATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

The below query worked for me:

```sql
SELECT NAME || '(' || SUBSTR(OCCUPATION,1,1)||')' FROM OCCUPATIONS
UNION
SELECT 'There are a total of '|| count(occupation) || ' ' || LOWER(occupation)||'s.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
SELECT CONCAT(Name,'(',left(Occupation,1),')') 
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
ORDER BY Name;
```

```
SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of',' ',Count(Occupation),' ',lower(Occupation),'s.') 
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION), OCCUPATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(NAME,'(',LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),')') FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY NAME;

SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ',COUNT(OCCUPATION),' ', LOWER(OCCUPATION),'s.')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads/problem/ :